Hydration error, difference between client and server side
What can i do to avoid the cleint side and server side differences/ hydration error? I want to initalize the state of carProducts to the localstorage, but this result in the hydration error. I tried to move initialization to useeffect but just more errors. How should i aproach this? I use Next.js
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
export const CartContext = createContext({});

export function CardContextProvider({ children }) {
  const initialCartProducts = typeof window !== "undefined"
  ? JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('cartProducts')) || []
  : [];
  const [cartProducts, setCartProducts] = useState(initialCartProducts);

  useEffect(() => {

    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      const localStorageData = window.localStorage.getItem('cartProducts');
      if (localStorageData) {
        setCartProducts(JSON.parse(localStorageData));
      } else {
        // Provide a default value if no data is found in localStorage
        setCartProducts([]);
      }
    }
  }, []); 


  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      window.localStorage.setItem('cartProducts', JSON.stringify(cartProducts));
    }
  }, [cartProducts]);

  function addProduct(productId) {
    setCartProducts([...cartProducts, productId]);
  }

  function removeProduct(productId) {
    const index = cartProducts.findIndex((id) => id === productId);
    if (index !== -1) {
      const newCartProducts = [...cartProducts];
      newCartProducts.splice(index, 1);
      setCartProducts(newCartProducts);
    }
  }

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={{ cartProducts, setCartProducts, addProduct, removeProduct }}>
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
}


Are you using page router or app router ?

page router is what i use
